# Does WPF have a "static box" control?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

Please see this image for what I'm referring to as a static box:

[image]

I'm not sure if that is it's proper name.

The box should be able to hold an arbitrary child control (panel etc.) inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WPF, it is called a **GroupBox**

See the MSDN documentation for the control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupbox.aspx

**How to use it**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <GroupBox Header="Test 1">
        <StackPanel Margin="6">
            <RadioButton x:Name="option1RadioButton" Content="Option 1" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="option2RadioButton" Content="Option 2" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="option3RadioButton" Content="Option 3" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Window>
```

**Cool features**

The WPF GroupBox is a bit more powerful than your standard Win32 group box.  Instead of just being able to set text in the header, you can set any sort of content you want, such as images, or other controls:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <GroupBox>
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="Test 1" />
                <Label Content="Test 2" />
                <Button Content="Test 3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel Margin="6">
            <RadioButton x:Name="option1RadioButton" Content="Option 1" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="option2RadioButton" Content="Option 2" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="option3RadioButton" Content="Option 3" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Window>
```

[image: group box with custom header content]

Answer (score 4):

Yep, that's called a GroupBox in WinForms/WPF world.

To set the text in it, set the `Header` property:

```
<GroupBox Header="Some Text">
  <Grid>
     <!--Other Controls-->
  </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```